# Repeater with dynamic number of columns

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

Repeater with dynamic columns.

I have to show columns based of settings. Sometimes I want to show Name, Age, Sex, Salary. So the stored procedure will return

```
Name  Age  Sex  Salary
-----------------------
 Rauf  23   M     10
 Amal  25   M     10
```

Sometimes I need to show Name and Salary only. So the data will be

```
Name  Salary
------------
 Rauf  10
 Amal  10
```

How can I design a `Repeater` control to show this type of tables having dynamic columns ?

Comment: Check this previous post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090378/variable-repeater-columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090378/variable-repeater-columns)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118427/variable-number-of-columns-with-repeater-control-asp-net-3-5

Comment: don't ask the same question again. You already received an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Unless perfomance i really crucial, I would take the easy way and use fixed columns (all of them) and just set visible=false in case you do not need them.