# Displaying information using repeater

Tags: asp.net, html, repeater

i am trying to display a list of products

i am using a repeater, the repeater is working perfectly but its not showing the information as i want. i want to display in columns each colums has 6 products and it repeat depending on the number of products.

this is a sample of the code that i am using

> page.aspx.cs

```
AllProducts = pm.GetProductOfMerchantByCat(ID, catid);
            ProductRepeater.DataSource = AllProducts;
            ProductRepeater.DataBind();
```

page.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater id="ProductRepeater" runat="server" Visible="true">
               <HeaderTemplate>
                   <ul id="ProductsContent" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
               </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                <div class="product">

                        <h4><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%></h4>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFeildQuantity" 
                                         Value='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>' 
                                         runat="server" />

                </div>

                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
               <FooterTemplate>
                   </ul>
               </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

any help would be great .. thank you

Comment: I don't understand your layout. Could you add an example of what the first couple of rows would look like. Just text will be fine.

Comment: This SO question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090378/variable-repeater-columns

Comment: @CrabBucket why not a listview with GroupTemplate and set to 6 the number of items in a group..?

Comment: @AdrianIftode. Why not indeed. You should write it up as an answer if you have time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey as per my Understanding you need to use DataList Instead of Repater.

Check This property

- RepeatColumns
- RepeatDirection

MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx